# Timeout error while connecting to SQL Server: Connection Error: Failed to connect to servername\instancename in 15000ms

Tags: sql, node.js, connection, connection-timeout

The error code is code `ETIMEOUT`. I am using SQL Server 2014, NodeJs version v12.16.2 and I am running this code in Visual Studio Code.

I have created the database and the table is also created with some records. For the server name, I have also tried giving the FQDN, but it didn't work.

This is the code snippet:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('<hHii</h');
});
const sql = require('mssql');
var config = {
   user: 'domain\username',
   password: 'mypwd',
   server: 'servername',
   host: 'hostname',
   port: '1433',
   driver: 'tedious',
   database: 'DBname',
   options: {
      instanceName: 'instancename'
   }
};
sql.connect(config, function(err) {
   if (err)
      console.log(err);
   let sqlRequest = new sql.Request();
   //var sqlRequest = new sql.Request(connection)
   let sqlQuery = 'SELECT * from TestTable';
   sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log(data);
      //console.table(data.recordset);
      // console.log(data.rowAffected);
      //console.log(data.recordset[0]);
      sql.close()
   });
});
const webserver = app.listen(5000, function() {
   console.log('server is up and running....');
});
```

Error:

```
tedious deprecated The default value for `config.options.enableArithAbort` will change from `false` to `true` in the next major version of `tedious`. Set the value to `true` or`false` explicitly to silence this message.   

node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:61:23  
server is up and running....  

ConnectionError: Failed to connect to servername\instantname in 15000ms

at Connection.<anonymous(..\SQL\Sample\sample\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:68:17)  
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:26)  
at Connection.emit (events.js:310:20)  
at Connection.connectTimeout (..\SQL\Sample\sample\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1195:10)  
at Timeout._onTimeout (..\SQL\Sample\sample\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1157:12)  
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)  
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {  
   code: 'ETIMEOUT',
   originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to INPUNPSURWADE\DA in 15000ms

   at ConnectionError (..\SQL\Sample\sample\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)  
   at Connection.connectTimeout (..\SQL\Sample\sample\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1195:54)  
   at Timeout._onTimeout (..\SQL\Sample\sample\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1157:12)  
   at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)  
   at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {  
      message: 'Failed to connect to servername\instantname in 15000ms',
      code: 'ETIMEOUT'
    },
    name: 'ConnectionError'
  }

ConnectionError: Connection is closed.

at Request._query (..\SQL\Sample\sample\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:462:37)  
at Request._query (..\SQL\Sample\sample\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:346:11)  
at Request.query (..\SQL\Sample\sample\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:398:12)  
at Immediate.<anonymous(..\SQL\Sample\sample\index.js:43:12)      
at processImmediate  (internal/timers.js:458:21) {
   code: 'ECONNCLOSED',  
   name: 'ConnectionError'  
}
```

Comment: Do you alrady have a solution? I have the same going on with a google cloud function that is triggered by cloud run. Strange thing;  sometimes it works and sometimes not. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Start menu in Windows, search for "Services" and open it.
2. Look for "SQL Server Browser"
3. Right click on it and go to Properties.
4. Switch "Start up type" to "Automatic"
5. Click Ok
6. Right click on it again and Start the service.

It should work after that!

Answer (score 0):

You might make a typo in host/port, or the server doesn't listen external interfaces (it might be configured to liten 127.0.0.1 only)

to check that the server is listening to incoming connections, run in terminal the following:

```
telnet <hostname> <port>
```

(mac/linux only)
If it says "Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused" it means the host is there but it doesn't listen the port.
If it says "Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out" then the host might not be there, ot doesn't listen to the port.

You may also want to check if your firewall allows connection to that server.

Comment: i tried this ...and it says "Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433: Connect failed"